# Html CSS list bullet to image not works

Tags: html, css

I want to change the `li` bullet to image background but it doesn't work and the image does not show. The same image of `li` background does not show. My HTML code is right according to W3Validator. Then why is my HTML `li` not working?

How do I make my `li` show in an image?

I used this code.

```css
 .heading{
        font: bold 11px verdana;
        color:#525252;
    }
    .altheading{
        font: bold 14px verdana;
        color:#C70C1F;
    }

    .bodies{
        font: 10px verdana;
        color:#303030;
    }

    .gheading{
        font: 12px MS Reference Sans Serif, Tahoma;
        color:#335784;
        
    }

    .gbodiesR{
        font: 12px MS Reference Sans Serif, Tahoma;
        color:#C70C1F;font-weight: 450;
    }

    .gbodiesG{
        font: 12px MS Reference Sans Serif, Tahoma;
        color:#006600;
        font-weight: 450;
    }
    
    li.cross{
    list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/Cross.jpg'); padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    li.tick{
    list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/tick.gif'); padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    }

    .phis_ico{ 
       background-image:url("https://shivkumar.in.net/phish914.jpg");
       background-repeat:no-repeat; 
       background-position:right; 
       opacity: 1;
       filter: alpha(opacity=80);
    
    }
```

```html
<table bgcolor="#D4281E" align="center" width="100%" border="0"
    cellpadding="0" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table bgcolor="#FFF" width="100%" border="02"
          cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                align="center" width="100%" class="phis_ico">
                <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="altheading" valign=
                    "center" align="center">
                      <u>Top Title</u>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="10" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="gheading" valign=
                    "center" align="center">
                      <p align="justify" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                        please help bepowbis my code 
                      </p>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="10" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="cross">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesR">
                      I am red cross paragraph
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="cross">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesR">
                      I am red cross paragraph
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="cross">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesR">
                     I am red cross paragraph.
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="cross">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesR">
                      I am red cross paragraph
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="tick">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesG">
                    I am green paragraph
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="tick">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesG">
                     I am green paragraph
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="8" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="gbodies">
                      <li class="tick">
                    </td>
                    <td align="left" class="gbodiesG">
                     I am green paragraph
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="38" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                      <a href="#"><img src=
                      "https://unionbankonline.co.in/pics/Conti3.jpg"
                      border="0" id="continue" /></a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td height="28" colspan="2"></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: it could be problem with CORS. Your url is https and that is maybe the reason why you cannot use it. Try some other url that is http

Comment: I get this error in the console for both tick.gif and cross.jpg: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 ()

Comment: I believe it's your cloudflare DDOS protection.  Once I have your sites cookies, the images load fine.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I see no unordered lists in your HTML code. If there is no list, there is no `<li>` element to render your image.

If your goal is to have two lists (one with your Cross.jpg and one with your tick.gif) then list-style-image should be attached to your `<ul>` tags, not your `<li>` tags. So your CSS would look like:

```
ul.cross {
  list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/Cross.jpg'); 
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  }

ul.tick {
  list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/tick.gif'); 
  padding: 0 0 0 10px; 
  }
```

Your HTML would look like this:

```
<ul class="cross">
  <li>List Item Here</li>
  <li>List Item Here</li>
  <li>List Item Here</li>
</ul>

<ul class="tick">
  <li>List Item Here</li>
  <li>List Item Here</li>
  <li>List Item Here</li>
</ul>
```

If you are trying to allow for different images on different list items, you will need to create background images for each: In this case your CSS will look like this:

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  }

li.cross {
  background: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/Cross.jpg')no-repeat;
  }

li.tick {
  background: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/tick.gif')no-repeat;
  }
```

and your HTML would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="cross"></li>
  <li class="tick"></li>
</ul>
```

EDIT: Just expanded your snippet and saw the `<li>` tags nested within your `<table>`. This is not [valid HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-li-element). `<li>` elements should be children of 
`<ul>` or `<ol>` elements.

Comment: Images are showing for me in latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and IE. It is important to note that your HTML is not valid and that can produce odd renderings in some browsers. You should wrap all of these <li> tags in a <ul> or <ol> element. Might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure you're not overriding your `li` style in another stylesheet add the following to both `li.cross` and `li.tick` classes

```
display: list-item;
```

See:

```
li.cross{
    list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/Cross.jpg'); 
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    display: list-item;
}

li.tick{
    list-style-image: url('https://shivkumar.in.net/tick.gif'); 
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    display: list-item;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Looking at your site, you indeed have a conflicting style rule that is hidding your bullets:

[image]

If you dont wan't to move this second css file, use the fix in this answer to override that value in your css classes.

**Please see this gif:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Pritam, i just tried my solution with developer tools on your site and it worked. Could you publish your site with this fix so i could give it a look?

Comment: No, you shouldn't make a second css rule, you should just modify your existing one by adding display:list-item; .. i think i might do something different to show you.

Comment: I added a gif just to show you what i was meaning and the result of it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the my website url from your answer, I vote up it but for my priority or privacy I don't want to share my website to anyone. Please remove all url from your answer.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4xvw70p2/1/. Note that the table does not display the images, but the updated HTML does.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the powers that be rejected my answer because it had your URLs in the code, just like two other answers do. Should we reject those answers  as well? I hope you were able to utilize the code and I think it is a shame that others looking for the correct answer will not find it here.

Comment: I should also note that the URLs in question appear in the original question. Might as well delete the whole thread.